# Can I store or cache images locally in React Native?

Tags: canvas, blob, react-native

I have a news app and I want to store the images locally when first gets them.

React Native's AsyncStorage accepts key-value string data. Can I use it?

In browser I was using `canvas` to get the data uri or`BlobBuilder` to get BLOB, not sure if it works in React Native.

Answer (score 2):

You could do so with something like the following:

```js
const STORAGE_KEY = 'yourkey';

Api.getImages()           // Replace Api.getImages() with your data source.
  .then((data) => {

    var images = data; 

    // Set a key for AsyncStorage, and Stringify the data
    AsyncStorage.setItem(STORAGE_KEY, JSON.stringify(data))

    this.setState({
      images : images,
    });

  })
```

Then retrieve it like this:

```
AsyncStorage.getItem(STORAGE_KEY)
  .then((storedData) => {
    var parsedData = JSON.parse(storedData)  
    // do something with the parsedData
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    // Could set the AnsyncStorage key here since it was not found.
  })
```

Comment: Thanks. Could you tell me more details about the `Api.getImages()` and `data`?

Comment: Sure, I was just using that as a generic function that retrieves data from some api. You suggested that the app gets images from somewhere, so you can basically replace the `Api.getImages()` function with whatever function you use to get your data.

Comment: You mean we should store data in Base64 format? How can one convert an image on-the-fly to Base64?